# VBA Crashes Excel When Closing an Access Connection

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

The following VBA code creates a new database from within Excel and adds a table to it. Everything works great until the line objConn.Close. This line causes Excel to crash with a BEX error. If I comment out that line the code runs fine but the database lock remains. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub openADB()
    Dim adoxTab As ADOX.Table
    Dim adoxCat As ADOX.Catalog
    Dim adoxCol As ADOX.Column
    Dim adoxInd As New ADOX.Index
    Dim objConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oCatalog As Object

    Const DB_NAME = "item_details.accdb"
    Const DB_PATH = "c:\temp\"

    'create the database
    Set oCatalog = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
    oCatalog.Create "Provider='Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';Data Source=" & DB_PATH & DB_NAME

    objConn.Open "Provider='Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';Data Source=" & DB_PATH & DB_NAME
    If (objConn.State <> adStateOpen) Then
        MsgBox "A connection to the database " & DB_PATH & DB_NAME & " could not be established. Program terminated."
        objConn.Close
        Set objConn = Nothing
        End
    End If

    'create a table for currency
    Set adoxTab = CreateObject("ADOX.Table")
    Set adoxCat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
    Set adoxCat.ActiveConnection = objConn

    'field properties
    adoxTab.Name = "tblCurrency"
    adoxTab.Columns.Append "Currency", adVarWChar, 3
    adoxTab.Columns.Append "Factor", adSingle

    adoxTab.Columns("Currency").ParentCatalog = adoxCat
    adoxTab.Columns("Currency").Properties("JET OLEDB:Compressed Unicode Strings") = True
    adoxTab.Columns("Currency").Properties("JET OLEDB:Allow Zero Length") = False
    adoxTab.Columns("Currency").Properties("Nullable") = True

    adoxTab.Columns("Factor").ParentCatalog = adoxCat
    adoxTab.Columns("Factor").Properties("Nullable") = True

    adoxCat.Tables.Append adoxTab

    'set up a primary key for Item
    adoxTab.Keys.Append "PrimaryKey", adKeyPrimary, "Currency"

    'give back memory
    Set adoxCat = Nothing
    Set adoxTab = Nothing
    Set oCatalog = Nothing

    objConn.Close '<== this is the line that causes the error
    Set objConn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but anyway try to declare `Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection` without `New` and set it to `New ADODB.Connection` on the next line.

Comment: Works for me with ADO/X v2.8.   Does set `Set adoxCat.ActiveConnection = Nothing` free the lock?  Probably won't make any difference but try `adoxCat.ActiveConnection.Close` instead

Comment: Your early binding do can replace the `Set a = CreateObject("b")` with `Set a = new b`

Comment: Most likely unrelated to your issue, but you should replace `End` with `Exit Sub` so you exit normally in that condition - `End` literally pulls the plug, hard stop.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input. ADO/X v2.8 accepted the code as written, as did ADO/X 6.1. I was using ADO/X v6.0 when the error appeared. Alex K's suggestion of ActiveConnection.Close solved the problem for v6.0.